# pd.wide_to_long() lost data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I'm very new to Python. I've tried to reshape a data set using pd.wide_to_long. The original dataframe looks like this:

```
     chk1  chk2  chk3  ...  chf1  chf2  chf3  id  var1  var2
0       3     4     2  ...   nan   nan   nan   1     1     0
1       4     4     4  ...   nan   nan   nan   2     1     0
2       2   nan   nan  ...     3     4     3   3     0     1
3       3     3     3  ...     3     2     2   4     1     0
```

I used the following code:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df,
                      stubnames=['chk', 'chf'],
                      i=['id', 'var1', 'var2'],
                      j='type')
```

When checking the data after these codes, it looks like this

```
                                       chk        chf
id   var1     var2     egenskap                      
1    1        0        1                 3        nan
                       2                 4        nan
                       3                 2        nan
                       4               nan        nan
                       5                 4        nan
                       6               nan        nan
                       7                 4        nan
                       8                 4        nan
2    1        0        1                 4        nan
                       2                 4        nan
                       3                 4        nan
                       4                 5        nan
```

But when I check the columns in the new data set, it seems that all columns except 'chk' and 'chf' are gone!

```
df2.columns
Out[47]: Index(['chk', 'chf'], dtype='object')

df2.columns
for col in df2.columns:
    print(col)

chk
chf
```

From the dataview it looks like 'id', 'var1', 'var2' have been merged into one common index:

[Screenprint dataview here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAfOe.png)

Can someone please help me? :)

Comment: `df2=df2.reset_index()`?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much :)